# Two countdown timers crash in same activity on android? [android]

Tags: android, crash, countdowntimer

I have two activity. ActivityA has a countdowntimer and when I start ActivityA , timer starts (60 seconds).

In 60 seconds , I start ActivityB and in ActivityA timer continue, Because if I don't do anything in ActivityB, when 60 seconds finish, I return ActivityA.

But 60 seconds before the end , when I return ActivityA, on create one more timer starts. Now previous timer and this timer crashes. So how do I prevent it?

Comment: @ianhanniballake http://www.extremepes.com/log.txt

Comment: It says you have a null pointer at `com.example.uygulama1.QRcode.onCreate(QRcode.java:138)` - can you post your `onCreate` method and point out that line?